# Как вывести содержимое текстового файла с пронумерованными строками?

Tags: linux, shell

Помогите разобраться.

Выполняется поиск текстового файла с наименьшим количеством слов.

```
$ find -name "*txt" | xargs wc -w | sort -g | head -n 1
```

Как вывести на экран содержимое найденного текстового файла с пронумерованными строками? `cat -n`?

Comment: Фигасе задачки задают админам. С такой не каждый кодер справится.

Comment: @Sergey, вы, вероятно, не поверите, но для unix-пользователя подобная «задача» — это уровень (условно говоря) «детского сада». одним словом: примитив.

Comment: Спасибо помогли)
find -name '*txt' | xargs wc -w | sort -g | head -n 1 | xargs cat -n

Comment: @Sergey, годный троллинг.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

варианты выдачи содержимого файла или потока с пронумерованными строками:

1. `nl`

   1. содержимое указанного файла:

      ```
      $ nl файл
      ```
   2. содержимое потока строк:

      ```
      $ какие-то команды | nl
      ```
2. `cat`

   1. содержимое указанного файла:

      ```
      $ cat -n файл
      ```
   2. содержимое потока строк:

      ```
      $ какие-то команды | cat -n
      ```
3. `less`

   1. содержимое указанного файла:

      ```
      $ less -N файл
      ```
   2. содержимое потока строк:

      ```
      $ какие-то команды | less -N
      ```
4. `awk`

   1. содержимое указанного файла:

      ```
      $ awk '{ print FNR " " $0 }' файл
      ```
   2. содержимое потока строк:

      ```
      $ какие-то команды | awk '{ print FNR " " $0 }'
      ```
5. `perl`

   1. содержимое указанного файла:

      ```
      $ perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"' файл
      ```
   2. содержимое потока строк:

      ```
      $ какие-то команды | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"'
      ```

---

у вас, как я понял, весь поток заканчивается выдачей **имени** файла. чтобы применить к нему любую из перечисленных команд, надо воспользоваться программой `xargs`, которой вы уже пользовались. например, передать это имя программе `nl` можно так:

```
$ команды возвращающие имя файла | xargs nl
```

Comment: А также grep и sed.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, свои варианты ответа здесь только приветствуются. это относится и к [другому вашему комментарию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594948/#comment806149_595159).

Comment: Не хочу плодить сущности. Ищущий да обрящет. Относится ко всем топикстартерам и им отвечающим.