# Как использовать регулярные выражения в env sh?

Tags: shell

Есть выражение, проверяющее что в строке присутствуют только шестнадцатеричные цифры:

> ^[0-9a-fA-F]+$

В окружении bash используется так:

```
if [[ $subcommand =~ ^[0-9a-fA-F]+$ ]]
     echo "OK"
fi
```

Как использовать его в env sh, чтобы получить тот же результат что и в bash?

Примеры валидных строк:

> a972b26d11a94a9063aa8b4ac3faf07a93fa47e3
>
> 234567890abcdef

Примеры не валидных строк:

> *1234567890abcdef
>
> zzzя1234567890abcdef
>
> xyz

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, **что именно** вы подразумеваете под словосочетанием «env sh».

Answer (score 2):

если под «env sh» подразумевается «*posix*-совместимая оболочка» (без дополнительных возможностей, реализованных, например, в программе `bash`), то, к сожалению, стандартом *posix* не предусмотрена возможность сравнения строки с регулярным выражением **встроенными средствами самой оболочки**.

но для такого сравнения можно воспользоваться возможностями входящей в стандарт программы [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

```
if echo "$subcommand" | grep -q -e '^[0-9a-fA-F]\+$'; then
  echo ok
fi
```

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал такую конструкцию с grep, но забыл про обратный слеш перед плюсом. Видимо в этом была моя ошибка

Comment: Мама дорогая, `[[:xdigit:]]`

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, это вы к автору вопроса адресуйтесь. я скопировал его придумку, чтобы не шокировать новой информацией.

Comment: Тем не менее я бы добавил в ответ возможности улучшения (не поменял,  а именно добавил).